# not received the site owner emails for the two specific orders

Tags: sales-order, order-email, magento2.3.4

I used Magento 2.3.4, but not received the site owner emails for the two specific orders.
the order has places but I didn't get Order Email, only two specific order,
I have checked all email settings, all are correct,

so I don't know now where I have to check for those order emails?
please suggest to me or assist me for this issue..

thanks in advance.

Comment: there is an issue with email failing where the recipient name has special characters in it such as umlauts or accents.

Comment: so did you mean that the customer email address names has special characters? problems

Comment: There was a known issue with 2.3.x where a recipient name with a special character would cause an exception. For example Mr Numan would work, Mr Nüman would cause an exception and mail would fail.